# '[CLLocationManager headingAvailable]' returning FALSE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, magnetometer, heading

I am having some issues with the following.

CLLocationManager headingAvailable

This always returns false meaning that the heading never updates (the function doesn't run at all) while the 'didUpdateToLocation' works perfectly.

I am using the iPhone 6.1 simulator. The strange thing is the locations work, I am able to get the long/lat just not the heading.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: One thing to check on, the simulator location tends to stick (at least for didUpdateLocations). Sometimes you need to kick the locations for it to start responding again in your code. I usually select Apple HQ then back to my custom location and things start working. Possible your item doesn't work in sim, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator does not support all hardware functions that devices do. I believe that heading is one of those functions that is not supported on the sim. You will need to use a device to test that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set these variables in your plist ?

Extract from apple documentation :

For direction-related events, you can associate two relevant strings with the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key:

*magnetometer*—Include this string if your app requires heading information.

*gps*—Include this string if your app requires course-related information.

Comment: But take this into account as well (from Apple Documentation) :

Important: If your iOS app uses heading or course events but is able to operate successfully without them, don’t include the corresponding string value with the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.